# Best way to use AMD modules within the Atom shell

Tags: node.js, amd, atom-editor, js-amd

Is it possible to use/require AMD modules from within the Atom shell? I understand that Atom has its own loader, when I try to load a AMD module using `require './lib/test.js'` it throws a `Define is not defined` exception .

[I know there are ways](https://github.com/jrburke/amdefine) to use AMD modules within Node, but I am still having trouble getting AMD modules to resolve inside Atom.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!